# How to filter all post on the basis of user_id in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have `1:N` relationship in `user` and `books` model. When I am making a new entry of `books` through portal everything works fine including saving the `foreign-key` of `user_id` in `books` table.

But when I am fetching the data every users are seeing all `books`. How can i filter the books as per login users?

## Book Controller

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!

def index
 @book = Book.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @simulation }
  end
end

def new
  @book = Book.new
end

def create
  @book = current_user.books.build(simulation_params)
  if @book.save
    redirect_to action: 'index'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end
....
```

Where as

## book model class

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

## User Model class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :validatable
 has_many :books, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

I tried by doing some modification in `Book controller.index` method but it's showing an error:

```
def index
 @user = current_user.id
 @book = @user.books
 @book = Book.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
 format.json { render json: @book }
 end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change action `index` from

```
def index
 @book = Book.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @simulation }
  end
end
```

to

```
def index
 @book = current_user.books.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
 # only books that belong to a user, then paginate on those records
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @simulation }
  end
end
```

Comment: what if the user isn't signed in? `current_user` only works with if there's an existing session.

Comment: This was for books that `belong` to a user. This was not a public facing part of the application. If you want a page that shows books of all users, then why do you need only `current_user` specific books ?

Answer (score 0):

`Book.paginate` loads all books, use `@book.paginate`